# Including Unmanaged C++ DLL as Content in WinRT

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-runtime, unmanaged

I am trying to use a C++ DLL in C# Windows Store app. I included the DLL file as **Content** with **Copy Always** option, in a project directory (which should map to an installation directory upon installation).

This works fine on a Desktop without a problem.

Based on what I have researched online, I cannot figure out why this method doesn't work for Windows Phone Emulator and Device.

Worth pointing out that the DLL is updated to the appropriate architecture (x64, x86, arm) with VS2015's **Pre-build event command**.

*Some unsuccessful attempts:*

I attempted using `LoadPackagedLibrary` in App Initialization just in case the DLL was not being loaded in time but didn't help (also meant messing up with DllImport I could do without!).

I would have thought `Package.appxmanifest` is where such dependencies are declared (or hinted) but couldn't find much mileage with this approach either.

Am I missing [something obvious] for an unmanaged DLL included as Content?
I've this feeling that this should be straight-forward 'cos many developers must have done this but can't figure or find a how-to example. Help!

Comment: *"I cannot figure out why this method doesn't work for Windows Phone Emulator and Device."* - *"Doesn't work"* is not an error description. Please provide information, how this fails, the expected behavior, as well as the observed behavior. (Extensive documentation can be found at [How to: Use Existing C++ Code in a Universal Windows Platform App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx).)